# C# new generic constraint not using highest constructor

Tags: c#, generics

Essentially, what we've got is this:

```
public class A {
...
    public A() { ... }
...
}

public class B : A {
...
    public B() : base()
    { throw new Exception(); }
...
}
```

But then:

```
public class Test<T>
    where T : A, new()
{
    public void doStuff() { B b = new B(); }
}
```

And no exception is thrown.  It's really quite confusing!  Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example. It's hard to diagnose it from what you've given. (You don't even use `T`...)

Comment: Are you creating a Test class and calling DoStuff? Would you do Test< B> myTest = new Test<B> and then myTest.DoStuff() and use T test = new T(); ?

Comment: Are you sure doStuff is actually executing? I did a simple test of this, and the exception is thrown when the new B() executes, as expected.

Comment: If you call doStuff() it should throw an exception, but that has nothing to do with the generics because as Jon says you are not using T for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code throws an exception as intended. I imagine you aren't using your Test class correctly since you didn't post the code.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Test<B> myTest = new Test<B>();
        myTest.doStuff(); // throws exception in B()
    }

    public class A
    {
        public A() { }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public B()
            : base()
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }

    public class Test<T> where T : A, new()
    {
        // I modified this because the intent is to use T correct?
        public void doStuff() { T test = new T(); }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it was an error in my test class.  This is really embarrassing, and I would appreciate it if someone would close the questions.  Sorry to waste folks' time.

Comment: @RichardRast We all do it, no problem. I appreciate marking the answer. Besides, I learned something new, I didn't know about the new() constraint until I read your question and I've been writing .NET code for a long time